# How do I specify a separate way to load sub graph schema via ApolloGateway?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-federation

I am using ApolloGateway to federate multiple subgraphs into one. Below is the code. The gateway will try to retrieve graphql schema from subgraph endpoint and forward the request to those endpoints as well.

My problem is that the schema is not readable from those server during runtime. I can download the schema during deployment time. I don't know how to pass the schema to ApolloGateway.

Is there a way I can specify the schema in a different way?

```
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
    subgraphs: [
      {
        name: 'product',
        url: '...',
      },
      {
        name: 'test',
        url: 'http://localhost:4001',
      },
      {
        name: 'user',
        url: '...',
      },
    ],
    introspectionHeaders: {},
  }),
  buildService({ name, url }) {
    return new AuthenticatedDataSource(name, { url });
  },
});
```